# What do these lights mean?

Tags: engine, lights, stall

When I stop the car (by hitting the brake pedal), the engine all of a sudden stops while on drive. Here are the lights I get:

[image]

What do they mean? Is it a battery problem?

Comment: Do you have a better picture?

Comment: Make, Model, Year, Engine size?

Answer (score 2):

The lights coming on is normal for engine off, key on. That is just the car illuminating most/all of the lights to verify the bulbs work.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the engine shuts off, when you come to a stop, it's likely a Torque Converter Lockup Solenoid keeping the Torque Converter Clutch engaged stalling the engine when you come to a stop

Comment: It could also be a short in the brake light circuit dropping the voltage to near zero.